# Any good way to calculate $\frac {\alpha ^ n - 1 } {\alpha - 1} \pmod{c}$

Tags: number-theory

I tried by multiplying modular inverse of denominator to the numerator and then taking modulo $c$, but there are problems when the inverse does not exist.

So is there a good way to solve this problem.

Constraints
$$ 1 \le \alpha \le 1e9 $$
$c$ is a prime
$$ 1 \le n \le 1e9 $$

Comment: If $c$ divides $\alpha-1$ with multiplicity $k$, you can compute $\alpha^n-1\pmod{p^{k+1}}$ and then divide by $\alpha-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $S_0:=1$ and then recursively $S_k:=\alpha S_{k-1}+1 \pmod c$ for all $k=1,\dotsc,n-1$. The last value $S_{n-1}$ is what you seek.

Comment: Its too slow to be just linearly calculated with n ~ 1e9

Comment: A better way would be to go like $ S_k := S_{\frac {k}{2}} + \alpha ^ {k / 2} S_{k - \frac{k}{2}} $

Comment: Sure, as long as running time is an issue. (From your question I understood that you are mostly struggling with the situation where the denominator is not invertible.)